# Making link of html.helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

Im creating a simple CMS for webpages...When i have created a new page i dsiplay the page in
a view like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
```

Can i embedd this pice of code in an anchor tag and point it to the proper adress.

Lets say i have created a page called games that have the `model.url = "/games"`
The way it is now, i have to write:

```
http://localhost:xxx7/games
```

To get to it...I would really like to just click on it.

EDIT:
Thank you for answering! Im sure the way you are describing is in the right direction. 
The thing is this, the page where i display my:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
```

Contains a table with maybe 10 different:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
```

If i do:

```
@Html.ActionLink( @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url).ToHtmlString(), "Index", "Games")
```

They all will poit to the same place, i need it to be dynamic so that each:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
```

Points to the url it represents.

Comment: I don't get it... what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like for @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
to be a clickabe link that leads me to the page that it represents.

Comment: `model.Url` is an array?

Comment: model.url is one of many properties i loop through in the view.

Comment: Im sorry, of course im looping through this object(s):
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)

Answer (score 3):

Read about: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp `@Html.ActionLink()`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link name or whatever", "your_action", "your_controller")
```

More information on: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, but anyway it may not work because I don't know why you are passing an url in your model. Is it an external url or internal that should redirect you to controller?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to use the Html.ActionLink to specify the controller and view.

```
@Html.ActionLink( "Display Name", "ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

So you could do something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink( @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url).ToHtmlString(), "Index", "Games")
```

But I see no reason you couldn't just drop it inside an anchor if you are generating the url's some other way - or if it is external to your own page:

```
<a href="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)">DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)</a>
```